# replace a specific pattern in a column using awk or gsub

Tags: awk, gsub

I have a tab-delimited file with columns as shown below:

```
 1   2   3    Score\x3e366\x3bName\x3elod\x3e41
 3   5   6    Score\x3e366\x3bName\x3elod\x3e41
```

I need to replace '\x3e' with '=' and '\x3b' with ';' in the 4th column. The output should look like:

```
 1   2   3    Score=366;Name=lod=41
 3   5   6    Score=366;Name=lod=41
```

Could someone help with awk/gsub to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How about `sed`?

```
more file.txt | sed -e s/\\\\x3e/=/g | sed -e s/\\\\x3b/\;/g
```

Admittedly, this blithely makes the assumption that those char sequences won't occur anywhere outside the 3rd column, but if that's permissible the above should work for you.

Comment: thanks a lot. It works fine, but i have been thinking if such pattern exists elsewhere, is to possible to restrict to a specific column?

Comment: why are you `more`ing the file ?

Comment: @Jidder Can you suggest a better approach?

Comment: Hi, this seems to be not working when this command is used inside python script.The output remains unchanged. Any clue of what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{col=$4; gsub(/\\x3e/,"=",col); gsub(/\\x3b/,";",col); sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,col)} 1' file
 1   2   3    Score=366;Name=lod=41
 3   5   6    Score=366;Name=lod=41
```

The general case where the column needing the replacements isn't the last column in the line:

```
$ cat file
 1   2   3    Score\x3e366\x3bName\x3elod\x3e41    foo
 3   5   6    Score\x3e366\x3bName\x3elod\x3e41    bar
```

is this (using GNU awk for gensub() and broken into separate lines for readability):

```
$ awk -v n=4 '{
    col = $n
    gsub(/\\x3e/,"=",col)
    gsub(/\\x3b/,";",col)
    print gensub("(\\s*)((\\S+\\s+){"n-1"})\\S+(.*)","\\1\\2" col "\\4","")
}' file
 1   2   3    Score=366;Name=lod=41    foo
 3   5   6    Score=366;Name=lod=41    bar
```